# How to write method to calculate average in Swift-playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

In swift I'm trying to write a method to calculate the average. Using the method below if i type average(5,10,15) I get infinity displayed in the swift-playforund

```
func average(numbers: Int...) -> Double {
    var sum = 0
    var count = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    var  ave : Double = Double(sum) / Double(count)
    return ave
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's so much easier with just a straightforward call to `reduce`:

```
let array = [1.0,2.0,3.0]
var average = array.reduce(0.0) {
    return $0 + $1/Double(array.count)
}
// average = 2.0
```

Comment: Loving the functional answer; much more swifty!

Comment: Caution: If this approach is done using `Int` type instead of `Double`, if the array size is large, the `$1/array.count` will be 0 every time, resulting in the average appearing to be zero. Use `Double` every time! Great answer though.

Comment: It is more efficient to1st reduce and then divide once by the count. It is also way more elegant.

Comment: Just a warning: this is about 50x slower than with the Accelerate framework functions vDSP_meanv. If you're doing this in a loop, use vDSP_meanv.

Comment: @GuillermoMP if the members of the array are larger than the Int can hold, it will overflow in runtime. So your comment is wrong.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the count property of the array:

```
func average(numbers: Int...) -> Double {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    var  ave : Double = Double(sum) / Double(numbers.count)
    return ave
}
```

Comment: Ok now I feel pretty stupid oh well it happens. Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't be more elegant to use reduce?

func average(ns:Int...) {
   return Double(ns.reduce(0) { $0.0 + $0.1 }) / Double(ns.count)
}

Comment: **Swift 3:** `func average(numbers: Int...) -> Double {
    return Double(numbers.reduce(0, +)) / Double(numbers.count)
}`

Comment: Just for completion: average is also called "arithmeticMean" Side question: would it be possible to create a generic avg method? so that it could work for Int,CGFloat,Double and the likes?

Answer (score 21):

While others have already pointed out the missing count variable, it is worth noting that you can do the average even more elegantly by using closures as follows:

```
func averagec(numbers:Int...) -> Double {
    return Double(numbers.reduce(0,combine:+))/Double(numbers.count)
}
```

Edited for Swift 4:-

```
func averagec(numbers:Int...) -> Double {
    return Double(numbers.reduce(0,+))/Double(numbers.count)
}
```

Comment: It worked for me! Just a note, with Swift 1.2 you have to specify "combine" before the "+"

Double(numbers.reduce(0,combine: +))/Double(numbers.count)

Answer (score 9):

```
import Accelerate

let avg = vDSP.mean(array)
```

This will be at least 50x faster than all other solutions posted so far.

Comment: Definitely better if your looking for performance. 

I ran some performance tests and found that a data set of 1000 values ran 92% faster, and a set of 100,000 values ran 99% faster than the reduce method.

Answer (score 3):

Just write `count = count +1` in your `for` loop.

Such like,,,

```
.
.
.
for number in numbers 
{
  sum += number
  count = count +1
}
.
.
```

And now function by

```
var avg:Double = average(5,10,15)
println(avg)
```

Answer (score 2):

You forget to increment count in the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting infinity because `count` is always 0 - it's never incremented. So the `ave` variable is always going to be equal to some number over 0, which is a divide by zero error.

Either use `countElements(numbers)` or increment count on each iteration through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did:

```
func getAverage(nums: Double...) ->Double
{
    var temp = 0.0
    for num in nums
    {
        temp+=num
    }
    let div = Double(nums.count)
    var average = temp/div
    return average
}
getAverage(21,34.5,28,79)
```

Note that I'm accepting **Doubles** as input, not just Ints. I'm being a little verbose at the end, but I was trying for readable code. I probably could have just returned:

```
 return temp/Double(nums.count)
```

at the end and saved a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3, functional style

```
func average(numbers: Int...) -> Double {
    assert(numbers.count > 0)
    return numbers.reduce(0, {$0 + Double($1)})/Double(numbers.count)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this method.

```
func averageOf(numbers:Int...)->Float{

    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers{
        sum += number
    }
    return Float(sum)/Float(numbers.count)
}

averageOf(20,10,30)
```

Comment: averageOf() would not work, without arguments you are dividing by 0